# How do I hide exposed filter options in Drupal View?

Tags: civicase, drupal-views

Using CiviCase and need to hide two case status' that we aren't using from Drupal Views exposed filters (Pending and Urgent).

Pending and Urgent are disabled in the CiviCRM Case Status UI.

Just want end users to see Ongoing and Resolved as options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accomplished using Better Exposed Filters.

Went to BEF Settings, scrolled down to "More options for status"

Expanded Rewrite filter options

Under Rewrite the text displayed added

Pending|
Ongoing|Ongoing
Resolved|Resolved
Urgent|

Results in only Ongoing and Resolved as options.

Loved Better Exposed Filters prior to using this feature, now if you could alphabetize options I could get some sleep!